# Digitally signing only the real executable, not the overlay/appended data

Tags: windows, executable, digital-signature

I'd like to digitally sign my executable file. Till this, it all sounds trivial. Is it possible to make a part of the executable which is kind of "configurable" without losing the validity of the digital signature?

For example installers often store data in the overlay. In their case it's completely acceptable and required to include the overlay into the calculation of the digital signature.

But in my case I'm curious if there's any way for example to that use case, when I sign a file and then just APPEND an extra hundred byte after the end. I'm not modifying ANY of the already signed bytes, just appending a few bytes. According to my knowledge it also invalidates the digital signature.

Is it completely intentional and impossible to do that I asked, or is there any hidden switch or something I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

From the [specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/c/5/9c5b2167-8017-4bae-9fde-d599bac8184a/Authenticode_PE.docx):

> Create a value called FILE_SIZE, which is not part of the signature. Set this value to the image’s file size, acquired from the underlying file system. If FILE_SIZE is greater than SUM_OF_BYTES_HASHED, the file contains extra data that must be added to the hash.